# Merge two dataframes such that one column array_contains other

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pyspark-pandas

I am currently working on a task that requires me to tokenize the conference titles on DF1 (column "name"), remove stopwords and count the number of occurences of each word.
What I have done so far is extract and filter the words (column "filtered"), and create a new dataframe DF2 (only one column "word") that contains a list of all distinct keywords.

What I doubt now is how to merge these dataframes based on whether filtered[r] contains word[r] for row index r.
Something similiar to:`df2.join(df1,F.array_contains(col("filtered"),col("word")),"inner").show()`.
Is there a way to do so?
Also, is there a quicker alternative to count per-year appearances other than join followed by a crosstab?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You already wrote the way, what is the problem?

Comment: Give as some sample output. Helps for better understanding.